# Best way of deleting multiple records linked in different tables in Laravel query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I've got a function in my Laravel 8 API that deletes a user's account, it also deletes any of data in any other table where their `user_id` matches the one of the account that's being deleted. One thing has become apparant quite quickly with this, is how can this be scaled, and whether there's a better, potentially faster and more reliable way to delete linked tables data.

On the other hand, am I doing it the way that would be fine for medium sizes web applications, my current code is:

```php
/**
 * Delete account
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function deleteAccount(Request $request)
{

    // attempt to delete account
    try {

        $id = Auth::user();
        $user = User::findOrFail($id['id']);
        $user->delete();

        $items1 = MyFirstModel::where('user_id', $id['id'])->get();
        if (count($items1) > 0) {
          foreach ($items1 as $key => $item) {
            $item->delete();
          }
        }

        $items2 = MySecondModel::where('user_id', $id['id'])->get();
        if (count($items2) > 0) {
          foreach ($items2 as $key => $item) {
            $item->delete();
          }
        }

        // ... other models here.

        // everything went okay!
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Your account has been deleted'], 200);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        // catch the error
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'We was unable to delete your account at this time'], 422);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into `Model` lifecycle events. In your example you want to delete related data when a `Model` is being deleted. So on your `Model`, do something like the following:

```
public function booted()
{
    static::deleted(function ($model) {
        $model->releationship()->delete();
    })
}
```

You can read more about [model lifecycle events on the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events).

Comment: and this would be reliable right? How is this exactly working?

Comment: Just an observation with this, I can't actually create an account now after adding that to my `User` model, I get `Call to undefined method App\\Models\\User::releationship()` upon trying to create an account as a 422 error

Comment: @RyanH You are replacing `relationship()` with your actualy relationship right?

Answer (score 1):

If your database uses foreign keys and the foreign key uses CASCADE DELETE. All references are deleted when the user is deleted.
Keep in mind that this should not be done always. For example when you have orders linked to users.

Comment: The `user_id` columns or equitant columns in my other tables (not the ID) are stored as `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();` so would this approach still work?

Comment: No sadly not. The only way is to manually delete records. Or by converting all those fields to foreign keys instead. Then you can delete the user and all other records will be deleted too

Comment: The `ON DELETE CASCADE` action for foreign keys is not supported by all engines. I don't think `MyISAM` supports it whereas `INNODB` does for example.